# Is there any HTTP response body in case of HTTP RESPONSE CODE = 400?

Tags: php, httpresponsemessage

I'm getting 400 response code for an HTTP request. I want to read the response message in PHP. I'm reading response code like this:

```
$options = array(
            'http' => array(
                'header'  => "Content-type: application/json\r\n",
                'method'  => 'POST',
                'content' => json_encode($data)
                ),
            "ssl"=>array(
                "verify_peer"=>false,
                "verify_peer_name"=>false,
                ),
            );
        $context  = stream_context_create($options);
        $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

        if(strrpos($http_response_header[0], '200')){
            echo '200'."<br/>";
            return $result;
        }
        elseif(strrpos($http_response_header[0], '400')){
            echo '400'."<br/>";
            return $result;
        }
```

I'm getting result = bool(false) in the case of response code 400.

Comment: Can you share more of your code? What does `$http_response_header` contain?

Comment: I updated the question. Please check

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (http_response_code() == 400)
    return true;
```

Comment: I have to read response body.

Comment: If you already sure the response is 400, just use `curl` and `curl_getinfo($res, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE)`

Comment: I'm not using CURL, I'm using file_get_contents()

Comment: 400 is bad request, no body contents

Answer (score 0):

Try to add to `'ignore_errors' => true` Your http options in context :

```
$options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header'  => "Content-type: application/json\r\n",
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'content' => json_encode($data),
            'ignore_errors' => true
            ),
        "ssl"=>array(
            "verify_peer"=>false,
            "verify_peer_name"=>false,
            ),
        );
```

Comment: I don't want to read the 'response code message.' I know that this request is returning a json string in response body which I can via POST Man, But I have to read this (response body) in PHP.

Comment: So question is wrong. There won't be any response body - Your request is wrong and server can't read this.

Comment: There is response body which I can see by hitting the same request from POSTMan Client.

Comment: I updated the question with more code. Please check

Comment: I've edited my answer - it should help to You according to [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/context.http.php), but in case of error (400) server shouldn't return any response - response code should be Your answer.